# Событие click на ссылках на сенсорном экране

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Когда я хочу перейти по ссылке на сенсорном экране, приходится нажимать на нее 2 раза, так как при первом нажатии срабатывает событие `hover`.

Пытался использовать `.unbind('mousenter mouseleave touchend touchstart')`, но это не работает.

Да и вообще `unbind` не работает, работает только в случае не передачи аргументов, то есть на все обработчики.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, сам решил простым скриптом:

```
if ("ontouchstart" in window || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints)
{
    $('*').unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
}
```

Comment: Проверьте на iOS.

Comment: работает, как раз на нем и проверял

Answer (score 1):

Есть решение, но есть и особенности поведения разных браузеров:

1.

```
$(".myMenu ul li a").on("touchend", function(event) {
  window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

2.

```
$('.myMenu > li').bind('tap', function(event) {
  var link = $(this).find('a');
  window.location.href = link.attr("href");
});
```

Про нюансы почитайте по ссылке:
http://sitr.us/2011/07/28/how-mobile-safari-emulates-mouse-events.html